# Why IIS7 treat a specific XHTML page as XML page?

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I try to access a page, I got an error like below, but I can view the full source code, the **source code has no problem**, I have no idea why IIS7 tells my browser the XHTML page is an XML? (It's not my browser's problem, cuz I asked my friends to test and he got the same result)

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location:
>   http://www.xxxx.com/xxx.htm
>   Line Number 44, Column 239:

The strange thing is, after restarting the IIS7, the page works well again, but maybe several hours later, another page will get the exact same error. This problem drives me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

XHTML *is* XML. That's kinda the point. It should be sent as `application/xhtml+xml` by the webserver, but IE still throws a fit if it encounters that content-type. Nevertheless, that is the correct way for a webserver to send XHTML data.

If your XHTML file can not be parsed as valid XML, then it is not valid XHTML either, and unlike HTML, the browser will generate an error, just like you're seeing. The XHTML standard requires it to do that, instead of trying to interpret some malformed tag soup, like a HTML parser would.

Comment: But at least it has some problem with IIS, as I mentioned, when I restarted IIS, the page work well then. And just now, another strange thing happens, when I try to access a page, FireFox asks me to download (a download dialog shows up), for the same page, when I use Chrome, it only displays source code, after restarting IIS (or just the site) it works fine again! It's really weird...

Comment: Which content-type are the browsers seeing?

Comment: The content-type in the html code is writen like this:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
I just tried to use Fiddler to monitor what was happened, Fiddler says the page content-type is text/vnd.wap.wml; charset=utf-8
Could you please tell me how to force IIS to output pages in text/html content-type?

Answer (score 0):

go into your mime-types section in INETMGR and add .xhtml as application/xhtml+xml
this is the correct mime-type which IIS will deliver with that file type, otherwise it pulls whatever is configured in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having sounds like your web server IS delivering your XHTML page as XML but your page isn't validated as XML. In other words you have a piece of web page code that breaks the rules of XML, like a missing end tag, bad attribute, etc.

All the posters above are correct.....if you use XHTML it should be delivered as XML. But if you want to remove the error, and cannot fix the web page your only option is to remove the XHTML sent as XML setting in your web server.